# Array creation syntax in Java

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

Here is the grammar for array creation in Java:

```
ArrayCreationExpression:
new PrimitiveType DimExprs [Dims]
new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs [Dims]
new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer
new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer

DimExprs:
DimExpr {DimExpr}

DimExpr:
{Annotation} [ Expression ]

Dims:
{Annotation} [ ] {{Annotation} [ ]}
```

Why here: `new PrimitiveType DimExprs [Dims]` `Dims` is in brackets? If it is in brackets then I can write this: `new int [2][2] [[] []]` where `[2][2]` is the `DimExprs` part and `[] []` is the `Dims` part. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer was in front of my eyes but somehow i missed it. Here is the reason from the Java Specification:

> The syntax [x] on the right-hand side of a production denotes zero or
>   one occurrences of x. That is, x is an optional symbol. The
>   alternative which contains the optional symbol actually defines two
>   alternatives: one that omits the optional symbol and one that includes
>   it.

This means you can write `String[][][] s = new String[2][][];`

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4